# "EXPLAIN PARTITIONS" in MySQL 8

Tags: mysql, partition, mysql-8.0

In an old project that we have not changed for some time, the following request is used for partitioning:

```
EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT * FROM table
```

Then, the list of partitions is retrieved from the column "partitions" of this request result, and the actions to be taken over the partitions are deduced from this list.

This project is deployed and running on multiple servers that use MySQL 5.7.xx.

Now, we are trying to deploy it on our new AWS servers, using RDS instances that run MySQL 8.0.21, but the "EXPLAIN PARTITIONS" request is not recognized, the error is :

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM table' at line 1

My questions are:

- Is there a MySQL page in which this regression is documented? I read all their pages about the EXPLAIN keyword but could not find any information about it.
- Has it been replaced by another syntax that gives the exact same result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Features Removed in MySQL 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-nutshell.html#mysql-nutshell-removals)

> The `EXTENDED` and `PARTITIONS` keywords for the `EXPLAIN` statement have been removed. These keywords are unnecessary because their effect is always enabled.

So the "new syntax" is simply `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table`.